# To populate field with same Label

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, dynamic-vf-component

Hello All i have fields those are coming from different different field set(they can have common fields) and i want to have a feature to copy the values of fields to the similar fields(common fields) on that page on click of a button. How can i do this . Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom setting for this. Create Custom setting which will hold field mappings. like, which field from field set is to be copied to which field on record level.